# nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream [Mastodon]

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, mastodon

I am setting up a Mastodon server on Docker on Ubuntu.

The server is up and running but when I try to access the site from a browser I get the error 502 Bad Gateway.

Looking in the nginx error log I can see entries such as this one:

```
2020/07/01 06:47:59 [error] 11686#11686: *1 connect() failed (111:
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
27.33.64.244, server: www.canberrasocial.net, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.canberrasocial.net"
```

I have no idea where it's getting the "27.33.64.244" in the above line as that is not my server's IP address, but I don't know enough to understand what this means.

Nginx is up and running and a check of my ports shows the following:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11684/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      510/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      631/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11684/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19691/docker-proxy
tcp        0    340 45.76.124.78:22         27.33.64.244:60825      ESTABLISHED 25063/sshd: root@pt
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11684/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      631/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      11684/nginx: master
```

I'm fairly new to linux admin so my apologies if this is a dumb question, but I'm really stumped as to how to resolve this issue. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "27.33.64.244" is not your server's address because it is the "client" address (please refer to the error log), which might be the "device" that you're using to connect to your server.

The real problem is that when nginx is trying to pass a request to your upstream at port 3000, it failed. Just by looking at your ports, I cannot see any process listening to port 3000, which might be the reason nginx can't pass a request. Did you forget to start the upstream?

I'm fairly new to nginx too, so sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I actually reimaged the server and did my whole install from scratch and now it works. The only think I did differently is that I installed my app directly rather then inside Docker, so I think my Docker configuration was wrong.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Great, I faced same problem and it was port problem. I opened pm2 log to find an error that prevent running on specified port.